# Why do the inhabitants of the lodge talk funny?

Tags: twin-peaks

I've started watching the third "season" (?) of *Twin Peaks*, and something that always bothered me about the first two seasons remains — the beings in the spirit world, or whatever the Lodge is supposed to be, speak in a strange manner, to the point they need subtitles even though they're speaking English. Why do they speak this way?

Comment: Out of universe: actors learn to speak the text backwards and then the recorded audio is played backwards again.[source](https://mashable.com/2017/12/04/twin-peaks-backwards-talking-david-lynch-laura-palmer-red-room/)

Answer (score 1):

Fairly certain there is not a canon answer, that being said there are a few different thoughts that spring to mind.

One is its simply the way they speak English kind of like an accent

Two is that its just the way a human brain processes their attempts to communicate the entities are so different that while a human can understand them to a certain extent its not easy to do so.